# I can not connect to server! Why?

Tags: android, sockets

Android app running on emulator

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LoginController loginCtr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loginCtr = new LoginController();

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
        });
    }

    private void login()
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Check connection!");

            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9010);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml contain:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

My Server running on localmachine

I checked 127.0.0.1 and 10.0.2.2 in android app

Comment: How do you know it's not working? What was expected to happen? What happens instead? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Comment: Your server isn't running on your phone which has IP 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Use http://10.0.2.2:8080/ where 8080 is your port number. If you just try 10.0.2.2, maybe  it won't work.
 or
 create a new instance of the emulator using the AVD manager and try using it.
 Foe genymotion it will be 10.0.3.2